# Solving inequalities with $x$ as a term and $x$ as an exponent

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to find the values of $x$ which satisfy the inequality:

$$x + 3^x < 4$$

I can approach the problem by setting the LHS equal to 4, and could proceed if I only had the term with $x$ as an exponent by taking logs, but the extra $x$ term means I would still be left with a term of log $x$. How should I approach this?

Comment: You can solve $x+3^x=4$ by inspection.  In general, (if you replaced $4$ by $5$ or such) I'd think you'd have to do it numerically.

Comment: $x<1$... see why?

Comment: There is no analytical method to solve $x+3^x=c$. In this case the solution is trivial but not in a general case.

Comment: This is not an equation, it is an inequality. An **eq**uation has an equals sign.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork now that you point it out, I can see it. Thanks